# How to get nav-bar to appear on two lines on smaller browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have a website with a nav-bar using the following HTML:

```css
.nav-bar {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.nav-bar a {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 16px 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 737px) {
  .nav-bar {
    max-width: 737px;
    height: 120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
    <a href="#">HOME</a>
    <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#">BOOK</a>
    <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
```

Which is fine until the browser gets to about 740px or less, where the navbar no longer fits on one line. I would like for it to collapse onto two lines but instead it gets a horizontal scroller. I have tried to solve this using the media query:

But this only creates a blank space beneath the nav-bar items without actually collapsing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `flex-wrap` property in your `.nav-bar`. This will wrap your `.nav-bar a` elements if they would overflow. Additionally you don't need `a` elements to display as `inline-block`.

```
.nav-bar {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.nav-bar a {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 16px 40px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the "display: flex;".

```
.nav-bar {
    background-color: white;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 737px) {
    .nav-bar {
        max-width: 737px;
        height: 120px;
        overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```